# Unix: Search for file contents

Tags: unix, file-management, search

I find the `find . -name "some-file"` command very useful to list all files matching some file name in a folder. Is there anything similar I can use to list all files that *contains* string?

If you needed to find all files in a directory that had a certain string of text in it, what would you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to search subdirectories:

```
grep -l "string" <pattern>
```

(<pattern> is a file glob pattern, eg *.txt)

Comment: Just found that out, hehe. Didn't know grep could work on directories as well. And if you add `-r` it will search subdirectories as well! For example `grep -lr "string" .`

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are using a system with a POSIX strictly compliant grep, ie which doesn't support the -r flag, but you still want to recurse in sub-directories, you can use this command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -l string {} +
```